# Unable to use pip3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04, spacy

I am unable to use `pip3` while `pip` and `sudo pip3` is working fine. It is giving me the following error. Is there a way i can correct the error. I tried uninstallling and installing the pip from get-pip.py , `sudo easy_install pip`, `sudo apt install python3-pip`. Still the error persists. The following details must help.

```
gajam@gajam:~$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
gajam@gajam:~$ which pip3
/home/gajam/.local/bin/pip3
gajam@gajam:~$ sudo which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
gajam@gajam:~$ pip

Usage:   
  pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and
                              CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort.
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to alternate CA bundle.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for download. Implied with
                              --no-index.
gajam@gajam:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip`
```

I am getting similar error when installing spacy en model (https://spacy.io/usage/models)

```
gajam@gajam:~$ python3 -m spacy download en
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 133, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/gajam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
gajam@gajam:~$ which python3 -m spacy download en
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/spacy
```

Comment: How did you install `pip`?

Comment: currently by " sudo easy_install pip"

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo pip install` is usually considered a bad idea, because it will interfere with `apt`. I recommend using a virtual environment.

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
python3 -m venv ~/venv
source ~/venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install <whatever you want to install>
```

Depending on the Python packages you want to install, you might need GCC and the development packages of the binary dependencies.

```
sudo apt install python3-dev build-essential
sudo apt lib<whatever library>-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am currently using that only. But can I stop the error if i want to install python packages using `pip3` in the system itself (not in virtual environment)?

Comment: You should check if you really need them installed system-wide. What is your use case? If you need to provide system-wide access to scripts installed in the venv you can symlink them in /usr/bin (or in another directory in PATH).

Comment: I am getting similar error, when I install spacy en model (https://spacy.io/usage/models).

Comment: I am quite sure there is either some PATH or PYTHONPATH confusion in your environment. Did you try the venv approach?

Comment: venv approach is working successfully fine. I am just asking if I can get rid of the errors out side the virtual environments.